# EndNote does not add pages for some references

Tags: microsoft-word, endnote

I have EndNote 7.0.1, and I am citing some references from google scholar using APA style on MS Word 2013.

some references have page numbers appear (works fine). but in most of the rest, about 60 references does not appear.

I have check them, there are page numbers in the (Pages) tab, I tried updating them, and also tried recreating the reference manually, did't work.

any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some thing

I think it depends on the type of the reference,the journal articles has pages added,
but the conference proceedings for example does not.

you can have pages added to the reference at the end of your document by converting it to journal article